# ImageJ Macro Path Issue

Tags: javascript, macros, imagej

In a macro I am writing, I am trying to export the results from a plug-in using the following structure:

```
savePath = newfolder+"\\"+fileid;
run("Export results", "filepath=savePath fileformat=[CSV (comma separated)]...;
```

where the *fileid* is simply a name of a file pulled from an array (i.e. "cell_1").

In the debug console, savePath reads "C:\Users\Main\Directory...\file.csv" (i.e. it appears correctly specified) but no file is output to folder specified. Instead, it is output to the ImageJ Plugins folder as a file called "savePath." However, then I manually insert the pathname inside the comment using "\" as the separator, it works.

I am aware that there was an issue concerning how ImageJ handles \ versus \ and / in the past, however I tried a number of fixes for this and none of them have worked. Things I've tried include:

```
replace(savePath,"\\","\\\\");
```

as well as

```
var s = File.separator;
replace(savePath,"\\",s);
```

and

```
replace(savePath,"\\","/");
```

and none have worked.

Interestingly, I use another macro in the sequence that uses the same formatting as savePath and it works fine:

```
directory = getDirectory("Choose input directory");
newfolder=directory+fileid;
run("Image Sequence...", "open=newfolder file=act" );
```

where, again, the *fileid* is simply a name of a file pulled from an array (i.e. "cell_1").

Any help or workaround on this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this is more of an issue with the format of the pathname. The pathname contained a space which ImageJ was having a hard time recognizing. In the future, I will avoid using spaces in my folder and file names. Also, the correct format for the export macro is

```
savePath = newfolder+"\\"+fileid;
run("Export results", "filepath="+savePath+" fileformat=[CSV (comma separated)]...;
```

using a "+...+" when inputting the variable.